# Sequencer Strip Addon

Tags: add-on, video-sequence-editor

I'm tinkering a bit around with some generators which would be nice as effects.
Is it possible to write an addon which generates images series as output for the strips. (Just generating them and importing is not an option)

EDIT:

I want to write an add-on which generates image-sequences for use in the VSE as strip (eg. visualizer for audio)

Comment: Sorry but there aren't enough details for an actual answer. But you could add a scene strip with your "generated effects" created in their own scenes.

Comment: I woud like to generate Imagesequences (animations) which directly could be used as strip (like a scene).

Comment: Why don't you just use a Scene? What would be the advantage of an Image Sequence particularly when you don't want to temporarily save them? Your question is really unclear without more detailled examples.

Answer (score 1):

When rendering, you can specify that Blender saves in an image format like .png.

As long as you have set a render range (default is 250 frames), you can press the "Animation" button in the Scene properties>Render tab, Blender will generate a frame sequence in the path you set in the Scene properties>Output tab.

[image]

Notice that the button labelled "File Extensions" is ticked? That tells Blender to add the frame number to every rendered frame. This will keep your frame sequence in order when you load it into the VSE later.

Comment: thanks, but i'm looking for a method to generate frames (in python) to integrate them directly into the VSE

Comment: You could add a scene strip then create a 100% proxy of it. This will generate a render of a an animation to use in the VSE with out waiting for a scene render.